# Limit of derivative exists at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is monotone and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=c$ for some finite $c$. Is it possible to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x)=0$.

From the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=c$, it is straightforward to show that $\lim\inf _{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x)\leq 0 \leq \lim\sup _{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$. But I'm having trouble figuring out what (if any) additional conditions are needed to ensure $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x)=0$.

Comment: No, at least because $f'(x)$ may not exist, for example, for all natural $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it’s not true. Take a non-negative continuous function $g$ that makes, on its way to infinity, infinitely many bumps of same height, each of them being less and less wide, so that the integral over the positive reals is finite.

In order to explicitly construct such a function, take a continuous $\phi$, that is non-negative, non-zero on $0$ and that vanishes outside of $[-0.003,0.05]$.

Then $g:x\mapsto \sum_n \phi\left((x-n)n^{47}\right)$ satisfies the above properties.

Now let $f$ be a primitive of $g$. Then $f$ is monotonic, has a finite limit at infinity, but its derivative doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

No. Put $f(x) = -\frac{1}{n}$ for $x \in [n, n+1)$.